# vim - I'm looking for plugin what adds tabulation inside block

Tags: vim

This feature is available in Intelij, and works like this:

I have for example some code (`|` is a cursor in this example):

```
|
doSomething();
variable = "foo";
```

And I'm adding it inside block, for example `if`:

```
if (true) 
{
doSomething();
variable = "foo";
|
```

Now after type closing bracket, plugin should add tabulation for code inside block:

```
if (true) 
{
    doSomething();
    variable = "foo";
}|
```

I hope I explained how it should work. Is there plugin for this?

Comment: What's wrong with this question? Why I got -1?

Comment: Don't you mean indentation?

Comment: Yes, it is. I just found `=` command, but I want it works automatically.

Comment: You can set autoindentation. Try these commands `set autoindent`   `set smartindent`

Comment: @sudobangbang i checked it but it doesn't working :( Maybe add binding to `}` character which runs `=%` command will be working correctly?

Comment: Yup. You're on the right track

Comment: I've tried this `:inoremap } }<esc>k :normal =%<cr>` and it does the binding correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In-order to indent a block of code inside {}, you can use `=%`.

It's just a matter of an insert mode mapping for <kbd>}</kbd> to insert `}`, and run the command `=%`

It can be done with

```
:inoremap  } }<esc>k :normal =%<cr>
```